# run selenium python script on android

Tags: python, android, selenium

I see some questions about it but I don't find an answer.
I want to run python on an android phone and run selenium (to open WhatsApp web).
I want to run it directly from the phone, without a computer at all.
Is this  possible? I will be   happy if someone will help me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.